# Is it possible to do nested if statements in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, if-statement

I'm trying to sort 3 elements in a list.  But i"m having trouble translating it to haskell.  Is it possible to do nested if statements in haskell?  I've been trying pattern matching, but it is taking me forever.

```
if (x < y) {
    if (z < x) swap(x,z);
} else {
   if (y < z) swap(x,y);
else swap(x,z);
} 
  if(z<y) swap(y,z);
```

this is what I have tried

```
intCMP :: Int -> Int -> Ordering
intCMP a b | a == b =EQ
           | a < b = LT
           | otherwise = GT

sort3 :: Ord a => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
sort3 cmp [a,b,c] = if cmp a b == LT then
                   if cmp a c == Lt then
                      if cmp b c == LT then
                         [a,b,c]
                      else
                         [a,c,b]
                   else
                      [c,a,b]
                else if cmp b c == LT then
                        if cmp a c == LT then
                             [b,a,c]
                        else
                             [b,c,a]
                else
                     [c,b,a]
```

Comment: "Yes" Furthermore, those nested if statements can be flattened.

Comment: what do you mean flattened?

Comment: Haskell doesn't really have if statements. It has if expressions. What makes you doubt their ability to nest?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you having trouble?

Comment: What went wrong when you tried that? Other than a minor typo (`Lt` for `LT`) that code works just fine when I try it.

Comment: Note that your `impCMP` function is just [`compare`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:compare)

Comment: See also the [`MultiWayIf` extension](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/basic-syntax-extensions#multiwayif)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This trick is that in Haskell `if` is not a statement, but an expression. It *returnes* a value from one of the branches, not executes the code there. In fact, `if` can be though to be just a syntactic sugar to a function `if :: Bool -> a -> a -> a` *(of course, no such function can exist, because `if` is a keyword; still, one can trivially implement such a function, if it is named differently, [like this](https://ideone.com/p5Tqpf))*.

So, yes, nested `if` statements are possible, just as any expression, like in

```
max x y z = if x < y then (if y < z then z else y) else (if x < z then z else x)
```

However, this is not directly applicable to your case, since you cannot do `swap` that easy: all values are immutable in Haskell. So, if you don't want to use monads or something like that, a solution may be to return the sorted list:

```
sort [x,y,z] =
    if x < y then
        (if y < z then
            [x,y,z]
        else
            (if x < z then
                [x,z,y]
                    else
                [z,x,y]
            )
        )
    else
        undefined -- implement other cases here
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say about being syntactic sugar for an `if` function. There is no such function, of course, and cannot be because `if` is a reserved token. You might say that it's a syntactic alternative to `Data.Bool.bool :: a -> a -> Bool -> a`, although of course the arguments are in a different order.

Comment: @amalloy Thank you, I'll change the wording. I am sorry if that sounds confusing. What I mean is that `if` is not something magical and *can be thought of* as a function `if :: Bool -> a -> a -> a`. Of course, there is not, and cannot be such a function, you are right. Still, one can just name it differently, effectively implementing the `if` operator in a function.

Answer (score 8):

As lisyarus said, you can do this. However, `if` is usually a bit awkward in Haskell; usually, pattern matching is a better option — this avoids the boolean bottleneck and allows you to directly deconstruct meaningful values. In your case, the most obvious thing would be to replace the ugly `== LT` checks with `case` expressions:

```
sort3 cmp [a,b,c] = case cmp a b of
      LT -> case cmp a c of
         LT -> ...
```

Since you always check all three anyway though, there's not really a need to nest the checks; you might as well check them all once:

```
sort3 cmp [a,b,c] = case (cmp a b, cmp a c, cmp b c) of
       (GT, _ , GT) -> [c,b,a]
       (GT, LT, _ ) -> [b,a,c]
       (_ , LT, GT) -> [a,c,b]
       (_ , GT, _ ) -> [c,a,b]
       (GT, _ , _ ) -> [b,c,a]
       _            -> [a,b,c]
```

Answer (score 0):

For three elements, it doesn't matter, but once you get to four, it really helps to have a notion of swapping, although I wouldn't go with your swapping regime. You can do this by giving each phase of computation its own function.

```
data Triple a = Triple a a a
sort3, sort3', sort3''
  :: Ord a => Triple a -> Triple a

sort3 t@(Triple x y z)
  | x <= y = sort3' t
  | otherwise = sort3' (Triple y x z)

-- Precondition : the first two elements are in order
sort3' t@(Triple x y z)
  | x <= z = sort3'' t
  | otherwise = Triple z x y

-- Precondition: The smallest element is first
sort3'' t@(Triple x y z)
  | y <= z = t
  | otherwise = Triple x z y
```